# Trouble with newton's method.

Tags: calculus, newton-raphson

This is the problem I'm doing and the start of the explanation of how to do it:

> Use Newton's Method to approximate to $4$ decimal place: $$\sqrt[3]{11}$$
>
> This would be the equivalence of finding the zero for $x^3-14=0$. So that would make our function $f(x)=x^3-14$. $x_1=3$ will be our starting point since it is closest perfect cube root.

Based on other example problems, I thought it should be $x^3-11 = f(x)$. Trying that, using the formula $x_{n+1} = x_{1} - \frac{x^3-11}{3x^3}$ I just kept getting negative numbers that just bounced back and forth, eventually, between -1.something and -2.something. So with my understanding of how I get f(x) is wrong, or the example problem is wrong again I somehow either screwed up the overly simple math of setting the cube root of a 11 to zero, or (despite checking and adding plenty of parentheses) I'm failing at my calculator input. Or some combination of those. I need held figuring what.

Comment: I have got stable $2.2240$ from initial $x=3$ in 15 iterations without any troubles. Check you formula and programming again.

Comment: Shouldn't the denominator in your expression be $f'(x) = 3x^2$ instead of $3x^3$?

Comment: Is it 11 or 14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must have been some typo in the formula that you have used. If you do everything correctly you will get something like this

```
3.0000
2.4074
2.2376
2.2241
2.2240
2.2240
2.2240
2.2240
2.2240
2.2240
2.2240
2.2240
2.2240
2.2240
2.2240
2.2240
```

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a typo in the explanation, it should be $x^3 - 11$ not $x^3 - 14$.  Then the approach you've described attempting is correct except that you've got the wrong $f'$ in your correction term.  It should be:

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^3-11}{3x_n^2}$$

Comment: Oh yea, sorry, typo on the post.